# Magento 2: Cron job not Calling Function [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, module, cron, custom, crontab

Running Magento 2 on my local WAMP Windows 10

I'm following below 2 Tutorials

[1] https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/setting-up-cron-jobs/

```
namespace Custom\Module\Cron;

class MyCronTask {

    public function execute() {
        /**
         *  Do some cool stuff here
         */
        echo "hi";
        exit;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When i run through command line it' not displaying message "Hi".

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group="my_cronjobs"
Ran jobs by schedule.
```

It only says "Ran jobs by schedule."

[2] http://inchoo.net/magento-2/running-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/

When i run

```
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
setup-cron: Please check var/log/update.log for execution summary.
```

In `update.log` it keep says

> [2016-09-26 09:59:38] setup-cron.ERROR: Your current PHP memory limit
>   is 80000M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more. As a user
>   with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit.
>   (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that,
>   restart your web server and try again. [] []

I already increase `memory_limit` in `php.ini` up to `80000M`. Cleared cache as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution

Thanks for help from atwix.com.

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/logging-system/

```
namespace Custom\Module\Cron;

class MyCronTask {

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->_logger->info("test-cron-message");
        $this->_logger->debug("test-cron-message");
        return $this;
    }
}
```

After running below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
php bin/magento cron:run --group="my_cronjobs"
Ran jobs by schedule.
```

It will save in `var/system.log` & `var/debug.log`, where you can see your logged data.

For `memory_limit` set it to `800M` in `php.ini` & it's working fine:)